# Laravel connection to sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, laravel, laravel-4

Trying to connect laravel to my local sql server 2012. But getting error:

[image]

This is the config file in laravel:

```
'sqlsrv' => array(
            'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
            'host'     => 'localhost',
            'database' => 'nih_bw',
            'username' => 'sa',
            'password' => 'root',
            'prefix'   => '',
        ),
```

Comment: Did you change the default settings as well? 
https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/config/database.php#L29

Comment: Yes, it is set to:  'default' => 'sqlsrv', - Håper du kan hjelpe meg Christer.

Comment: You need to provide more information about your local system and server setup; linux/windows?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to install the PDO driver for MS SQL Server:

http://pecl.php.net/package/PDO_DBLIB

Install with the command:

```
pecl install PDO_DBLIB
```

If you are developing on a Windows machine:

http://pecl.php.net/package/pdo_sqlsrv

Install with:

```
pecl install pdo_sqlsrv
```

Comment: Describe? What system? Do you have php5-dev installed? Do you have php-pear installed?

Answer (score 0):

on windows, you will need to install `pdo_sqlsrv` from 
http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php